# Title (in ASP.NET @ Page directive) not rendering in web page

Tags: asp.net, html, validation

I was intending on use the Title attribute in the @Page directive to customise each pages title, but it simply doesn't appear to do anything.

The site uses master pages - I don't know if that is a consideration.

Master Page snippet:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="brightnorth.master.vb" Inherits="brightnorth" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
etc....
```

Page snippet (from http://www.brightnorth.com/about/aboutus.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/brightnorth.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="aboutus.aspx.vb" Inherits="about_aboutus" Title="Brightnorth.com: About Us" %>
```

What is more, if I run the page through the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brightnorth.com%2Fabout%2Faboutus.aspx), it complains about...

> end tag for "head" which is not finished

..whereas the the  tag *is* present in the source code.

I've already got a workaround in place, but it's annoying the hell out of me, so I'm determined to find a resolution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops... A basic error! [aren't they always?]

Anyone spot a missing `runat="server"` in the  element?

Oops.

Comment: Doh!  I'd checked one of my own apps and didn't spot the missing runAt server... sigh...

Comment: Blackmael - this was a copy & paste - how the hell did I lose the attribute along the way? Oh well...

Comment: I think folks vote things down when you post a new item instead of using the "add comment" feature against your original post.  This happened to me the other day :(

Comment: Indeed - it was an answer to the question rather than an edit to the question.... Not to worry - it matters little. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use the HTML  tag as well :)

In your master page, inside the head tag you should have:

```
<title><%=Title%></title>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_title.asp

Comment: This should not be explicitly required.  The Title attribute of the Page directive is supposed to fill it in.

Comment: Nah, you're barking up the wrong tree there. The Title attribute of the page directive should be an entire alternative to the <title> element. In your example, you'll get a 'Title not defined'-type error.

Comment: yeah ... forgot about that... and I write ASP.NET all day :) We haven't touched our masters for months though :) To me a web page is just a bunch of controls in content placeholders :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to have, in the masterpage, if the title is coming from the page directive:

```
<head runat="server">
<title><%=Page.Title%></title>
</head>
```